# Microsoft Access: VBA Window automatically selected without Mouse Click

Tags: microsoft-access

Like the Title suggests, I have a problem when I'm viewing the properties of a form in Microsoft Access, if the mouse hovers over the VBA window, particularly a title bar, the focus goes from the Properties window to the VBA window even without a mouse click!

I've used Microsoft Access since 1998 and never seen any behavior like this.

I'm using Microsoft Office Professional 2019, Microsoft Access 2019 MSO (16.0.11629.20210) 64-bit.  Click to Run.

---

Several months later, I still have not found an answer - not for searching on the net!  I cannot believe this behavior doesn't bother anyone else?  Nobody else has seen this?

The solution I've found is to shrink the design window about 2 inches on the left side, and put my properties window there in that 2 inches on the left (i have two screens) and I put the VBA window in the left.  This way, if I float (accidentally or otherwise) into over or onto the VBA window it doesn't hide the properties window - which in my opinion (I know it says not to use opinions - but I think it's germane here) should be on top of ALL windows!

Another solution I Just found - which I think this will be better than the shrinking of the design window, and allow me to keep both the windows maximized-  If you double-tap the F4 key, it hides, and then shows the Properties window and brings it in front of the VBA window (Where it's supposed to be!!) - It's better than giving up the real estate in the Design window, and is also easier than moving the vba window and finding the properties box again.

I swear, each time I upgrade MS Access I get more and more disappointed with these meaningless changes they apply.

I'm still looking for the holy grail-  where the application will just keep the property window on top of the VBA window - especially if I didn't click on the VBA window!!

-Brian Prenovost
 (Frustrated with the VBA window taking all the attention!)

Comment: Does this only happen in Access? And does it only happen in a specific project? (Might be a form timer)

Comment: When I said I had never seen that before, I was incorrect - You're right, I've seen odd behavior like this when I had a form timer going but no, it seems to happen in all my databases - I have about 10 different systems that I wrote, and maintain in Access, and they all do it.  (I just verified that, and yes, it's not just one database it happens in)  After I had that problem with form timers, I have avoided using that "feature" ever since.